# Find location address for sepcific element in array

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, memory-address

I want to know how to find memory address for specific Index in three dimensioned array without do that by code such as i have  `array[5][5][6]` I want to find the location in memory for index element `array[2][2][2]` if i use address `500` for example in memory for the first element in array.

Comment: Many languages have arrays. Which one are you using? Please add the appropriate tag for it to your question.

Comment: @JeroenMostert i don't use any programming language i want to find it with equations

Comment: But what language are your *arrays* in? The idea of array elements having a memory address is most closely associated with C. It makes no sense to talk of arrays having memory addresses unless you have specified how they are arranged in memory, and that's what the language specifies.

Comment: @JeroenMostert if i use any programming language i will use `C` or `C#`, my array is fixed length and the but in static allocation where all elements arrange in the memory behind each other

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether the language you're using specifies [row- or column-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) for it's array addressing/allocation.

Since you mentioned C in your comments, which uses the row-major scheme, I'll describe that first.

Suppose you have a 3-dimensional array, `int arr[X][Y][Z];` where ***X***,***Y***, and ***Z*** are natural numbers.

An example might be in a grid split over several pages, where the data of interest is has a particular **page**, **row** and **column**.

We're interested in the data stored at a given point, **(*a*,*b*,*c*)** (i.e. `arr[a][b][c]`). In a row major system, the point **(*a*,*b*,*c*)** denotes the **a<sup>th</sup> page**, the **b<sup>th</sup> row**, and the **c<sup>th</sup> column**.

To compute the offset of a given point in that array, using a **row-major system**, use the following computation:

```
offset = a*Y*Z + b*Z + c
```

So

```
arr[a][b][c] == *(arr + a*Y*Z + b*Z + c)
```

In a **column-major system**, the importance of the indices is reversed. So point **(*a*,*b*,*c*)**  would describe the **a<sup>th</sup> column** in the **b<sup>th</sup> row** on the **c<sup>th</sup> page**.

Accordingly, the offset becomes:

```
offset = a + b*X + c*X*Y
```

i.e.:

```
arr[a][b][c] == *(arr + a + b*X + c*X*Y)
```

Why does any of this matter? Locality. It determines how you'll loop over the array. In a row-major system, the *last* index is contiguous, in that you should iterate over it first before increasing the other ones in order to not jump all over the memory space. The opposite is true in a column-major system.

Suppose we have a 6x7x8 array returned by a function: `int arr[6][7][8];` Let's say that `arr[0][0][0]` is at address 0x1000. In a row-major system,`arr[0][0][1]` will be at 0x1001; immediately adjacent to `arr[0][0][0]`.

In a column-major system, though, `arr[0][0][1]` will be at 0x102A, nowhere near (relatively speaking) `arr[0][0][0]`. If we were dealing with a large array and unaware of the majority system our language implemented, we could waste a lot of time by leaping all over the memory space unnecessarily.